# Blank level in SharePoint

Tags: powershell, site-collection, 2016

Running Get-SPsite to list all site collections and i found the second site level is blank ? WHY?

```
Url                                                     CompatibilityLevel  
---                                                     ------------------  
https://site1.com                                             15   
https://site2.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, It's a strange behavior, Although the `CompatibilityLevel` is optional in the command of creating a `New-SPSite`. but in a case of this parameter is not specified, **the CompatibilityLevel will default to the highest possible version for the web application depending on the CompatibilityRange setting.**

**Note:** The CompatibilityLevel values can be either 14 for SharePoint Server 2010 sites or 15 for SharePoint Server 2013/2016 sites.

> **So** the **CompatibilityLevel** must have a value that denote to the template version.

So the solution for such errors can't be predicted. Meanwhile, I suggest as a type of tracing to try to

- Create a new Site collection via PowerShell, close the PowerShell and reopen it again as administrator, then perform `Get-SPsite` and check if the CompatibilityLevel is displayed or not!!
- If CompatibilityLevel is not displayed, try to Create a new site collection via Central Administration then Open PowerSehll as Administrator and perform `Get-SPSite` and check if you got the same issue or not!

Comment: Thank you, your guidelines is very useful, I restart the power-shell not the level is displayed.